# Optimizing order of graph reduction to minimize memory usage

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, software-engineering, program-optimization

Having extracted the data-flow in some rather large programs as directed, acyclic graphs, I'd now like to optimize the order of evaluation to minimze the maximum amount of memory used.

That is, given a graph {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 3 -> 5}, I'm looking for an algorithm that will decide the order of graph reduction to minimize the number of 'in-progress' nodes, in this particular case to decide that it should be reduced in the order 1-2-3-4-5; avoiding the alternative ordering, in this case 4-1-2-3-5, which would leave the output from node 4 hanging until 3 is also complete.

Naturally, if there are two nodes using the output from a third, then it only counts once; data is not copied unnecessarily, though it does hang around until both of those nodes are reduced.

I would also quite like to know what this problem is called, if it has a name. It looks similar to the graph bandwidth problem, only not quite; the problem statement may be defined in terms of path/treewidth, but I can't quite tell, and am unsure if I should prioritize learning that branch of graph theory right now.

Comment: The problem can be expressed as an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), but not a linear one as far as I can tell.